# PHP Form Confirmation Failure to Call Ajax Script

Tags: php, ajax, forms

I have the following PHP/Ajax problem couldn't seem to find a relevant similar question at the present. I have a site where email is successfully sent from a form, however the Ajax part of the script is not called properly. When things work properly, what is supposed to happen is the user clicks submit, Ajax script is called for form validation. This part works then the email is sent out, however the failure is that the Ajax script is then not called after sending the email to close the submit window and say thanks, etc.

I think my problem is that I am missing a line of code somewhere in PHP to call the success portion of the Ajax script.

The scripts are attached below:

**PHP Code**

> ```
> <?php 
>  $emailTo = myemail@gmail.com';
>  $subject=$_REQUEST['subject'];
>  $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
>  $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
>  $msg=$_REQUEST['message'];
>
>  $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nMessage: $msg";
>  $headers = 'From: '.$name.' <'.$email.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;
>
>  mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers); 
>
> ?>
> ```

**Ajax Code**

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "email.php",
   data: params,
   success: function(response){
    if(response){
     var responseObj = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
     if(responseObj.ResponseData)
      alert(responseObj.ResponseData);
    }
    ResetInput();
    $('#submitButton').removeAttr('disabled');
    ClosePopupWindow();
   },
```

If needed the full Ajax code is at the following gist - https://gist.github.com/4117065

Comment: so this portion if(responseObj.ResponseData)
      alert(responseObj.ResponseData);
    } is not working?

Comment: try `alert(response)` ..

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to do this to track the error:

in php:

```
if (mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers)){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo get_last_error();
}
```

in jq:

```
if(response == "success"){
   //do your stuff
} else {
   //track the error
   alert(response);
   console.log(response); // you can chose either way, console.log() is the new black xD
}
```

I worked with ajax/php a lot lately, and in the most cases that ajax don't work is because php threw some kind of silly error :P

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize you used parseJSON, are you really expecting an json object from the php? because I don't see any in your php code. you would have to build an array in php and use json_encode(); to build a json object as response. If you are using only a plain string as response then don't use the parseJSON.

Answer (score 0):

In the .php file test if the mail has been sent witought error (returns bool http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) `$response = mail(...` then `json_encode($response['ResponseData'] = $success);`
In the js you are refering to a member that doesn`t exist: ResponseData

Answer (score 0):

The php script does not echoing any thing so the response is null.you can echo something in php as a reseponse,the code will work